# How to properly create a kernel in C and link to bootloader

Tags: c, assembly, x86, bootloader, osdev

I have a simple bootloader in assembly here:

```
;initialization type stuff
[bits 16]
[org 0x7c00]

;make message and print it
mov si, MESSAGE
call print

;infinite loop to stall
jmp $

;print "method"
print:
    pusha
    print_loop:
        mov al, [si]
        cmp al, 0
        jne print_char
        popa
        ret
    print_char:
        mov ah, 0x0e
        int 0x10
        add si, 1
        jmp print_loop

;actual assigning of message
MESSAGE: db "Hello World!", 0

;padding & magic number (end)
times 510-($-$$) db 0
dw 0xaa55
```

And my goal is to have most of the OS programmed in C, and at the moment I'm trying to properly link the bootloader and kernel in C:

```
void kernel_main()
{
    printf("Hello World!");
}
```

How would I link these together and compile them into something I can open in qemu/any normal computer?

Comment: What compiler, assembler, link, toolchain do you use?   And what provides a `printf` implementation?

Comment: At the moment I've only been writing in assembly, and I use NASM to compile it and qemu to run it. I don't have a link or toolchain because I'm not sure what those are. I assume the linker is for compiling the C code into the binary file. And now that I think about it, I won't be able to use printf because it's in a library... so I guess I'll have to use that VGA or something code I've seen being used.

Comment: A *linker* is a program that takes multiple object files and links them into one large program.  Typically, you use compilers to generate assembly files, assemblers to assembly them into object files and linkers to link all these object files into one program.  Before diving deeper into your kernel project, I recommend you to get familiar with how linking works as it is a very important part of the puzzle.

Comment: You've implemented `puts` (without the trailing newline, so `print` is a good name for it).  You should call that from your C, because you don't have a `printf` (which would imply support for *formatting* in the format string, like `%d`)

Comment: NASM doesn't seem to be able to compile .asm into .o. It doesn't seem to have an object file output option. Do I use gcc for this?

Comment: Use `nasm -felf32 boot.asm -o boot.o`to assemble to an object file. You can then link with LD (or GCC).

Comment: Be aware that GCC doesn't eally generate proper 16-bit code. If you are going to use GCC I recommend your bootloader enter into protected mode and writing a 32-bit kernel (or enter 64-bit long mode from the bootloader for a 64-bit kernel). If yuo want to create a 16-bit realmode kernel consider Alexey's [Small C Compiler](https://hackaday.io/project/5569-smaller-c),Openwatcom C or BCC (Bruce's C compiler).

Comment: This is a very simply bootloader that is linked with a 32-bit _C_ kernel that runs in protected mode. The bootloader enters 32-bit protected mode before calling into the kernel. The kernel is loaded after the bootloader at 0x7e00. Most of the heavy lifting is done with a specialized linker script. http://www.capp-sysware.com/misc/osdev/linkedboot_kreloc/

Comment: Using `nasm -f elf32 test.asm -o test.o` gives `test.asm:3: error: unrecognised directive [org]`.

Comment: @liaquore That is correct.  Deciding where which parts of the program end up is the job of the linker and can be controlled by means of a *linker script.*  If you generate object files, there is no point in using the `org` directive.

Comment: Yes you can't use the ORG directive when using `-felf32` (you must remove it from the ASM file). You have to set the ORG (VMA) address with the linker. For example `nasm -felf32 test.asm -o test.o` `ld -melf_i386 -Ttext=0x7c00 --oformat=binary test.o -o test.bin` should generate a bootloader `test.bin` .It is preferable to use a linker script rather than use `-Ttext=0x7c00` . The link I have above uses a linker script.

Comment: What kind of things need to be defined in a linker script?

Comment: @liaquore The linker script defines which parts of the binary go to which parts of memory.  You can define quite a few things in linker scripts, it's a powerful concept.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How to properly create a kernel in C and link to bootloader

Don't.

An OS is typically many separate executable files (boot loader, kernel, GUI, text editor, web browser, ...) that are not linked together into a single massive file that does everything (e.g. "Ubuntu.exe").

For boot loaders for 80x86; in general you may have:

- a boot loader for BIOS designed for unpartitioned storage devices (e.g. ancient floppy disk)
- a boot loader for BIOS designed for "MBR partitioned" storage devices
- a boot loader for BIOS designed for "GPT partitioned" storage devices
- a boot loader for BIOS designed for bootable CDs ("no emulation El Torito")
- a boot loader for BIOS designed for PXE/network boot
- a boot loader designed UEFI (and compiled for 32-bit)
- a boot loader designed UEFI (and compiled for 64-bit)

Each of these things involves some very different code (boot loader file formats, firmware restrictions, firmware APIs, where to get kernel from, etc).

You want to ensure that any of your boot loaders can work with the same kernel (and ensure that one specific boot loader that might be the wrong one hasn't been built into/linked with the kernel).

Don't forget that (eventually, not during early development) end users download/obtain some kind of "OS installer"; and the "OS installer" determines the correct boot loader to install with the OS (likely after asking the user if/where/how they want the OS to be installed and after detecting various pieces of information about the computer the OS is being installed on - what type of CPU, what type of firmware, what type of partitioning scheme, ...). You can't know which boot loader is the right boot loader until the "OS installer" has done a lot of work (and can't know which boot loader is the right boot loader when building your project).

Comment: So inside my bootloader I can do a reference to an external file e.g. kernel.o?

Comment: @liaquore :usually what people do is compile their _C_ (and assembly) code,then link it, and create a binary image of the kernel that is separate from the bootloader. What they do is use a mechanism that forces their entry point to their kernel to be the instructions at the beginning of the binary image. That way if you load the kernel starting at physical address 0x07e00 (I use 0x7e00, but it could be any address) you jump to the address 0x07e00 to start the kernel running.

Comment: @liaquore: One of the jobs of a boot loader is to find and load (or download) other files (config file, kernel, initial RAM disk, ...). Boot loader must do some other things (e.g. get a memory map from firmware) and may do a lot of other things (e.g. set up some default video/output, decompress files, setup up paging, find various firmware tables, auto-detect which kernel is the best kernel to start, etc)